# Given that $y_p(x)=\sin{x}-\cos{x}$ is a solution for $\frac{dy}{dx} +y=2\sin{x} $, find the general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Given that $y_p(x)=\sin{x}-\cos{x}$ is a solution for $\frac{dy}{dx} +y=2\sin{x} $, find the general solution**

The answer said that the general solution to $\frac{dy}{dx} +P(x)y = 0$ is $y_c(x) = Ce^{-x}$, which I'll accept.

Then the solution key just ended with saying that we have to add the "general solution" and the "particular solution to get $Ce^{-x}+\sin{x}+\cos{x}$ which I don't understand why

Comment: How much linear algebra do you know? There is an answer to your that goes through some manipulations and there is an answer that illuminates a deeper structure to these sorts of problems.

Comment: You should have learned that $y_g=y_p+ y_h$ where $y_g$ is the general solution, $y_p$ is a particular solution, and $y_h$ is the solution set to the associated homogeneous DE $y'+y=0$. You can solve $y'+y=0$ by finding the characteristic polynomial and proceeding formally.

Comment: These are the very elementary things of the course of "Differential Equation". Read your book carefully, you will get your answer.